# <div> with FLASH content covering entire screen | ENABLE CONTENT BELOW?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, html

I am wondering it its possible to have a flash file contained in a `<div>` that covers the entire screen. I have already done that but my question is...

**Can you still have the flash content in the `<div>` and have it transparent and use the html buttons below the `<div>`?**

I would like to keep the flash layer active all the time but how can I use the buttons below? I can't even copy or highlight text.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Assuming you mean underneath the Flash app not below. I think that's what wmode=transparent not sure about text selecting though

Answer (score 0):

If the div covers the whole screen are the buttons below the screen and no longer visible or did you place the buttons so they are not below the div but are fixed in place at the bottom of the screen?  In which case you should be able to give them a higher z-index than the div containing the flash. That way they are on top of the flash div and should be clickable.

```
<div id="flash" style="z-index:1;">
<div id="buttons" style="position:fixed; bottom:0px; z-index:4;">
```

You can also make the flash div clickable to show/hide the buttons that you've placed with fixed position in case the flash really does take up the whole screen. No need to make the flash transparent.